# Update in nested array based on Date queries may not work properly (or maybe I am doing sth wrong.. )

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Create collection "test", and insert one document into it:

```
   {
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "pointsBalances" : [ 
        {
            "period" : "2020",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2020-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"),
            "value" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "period" : "2019",
            "startDate" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2019-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"),
            "value" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Then please perform update - it should work properly:

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
  {$and: [ {'_id': 1}, {"pointsBalances.period": '2019'}]},
  {$set: { "pointsBalances.$.value": 100 } }
)
```

Now lets try to update based on dates:

```
   db.getCollection('test').update(
{ $and: [
    {'_id': 1},
    {"pointsBalances.startDate": {$lte: ISODate("2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
    {"pointsBalances.endDate": {$gte: ISODate("2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}
  ]},
{$set: { "pointsBalances.$.value": 200 } })
```

It seems that wrong element is is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB updates the first matching document to the condition, try elemMatch

```
 db.michel.update(
{ $and: [
    {'_id': 1},
    {"pointsBalances" : { 
        "$elemMatch" : { $and: [

                    {"startDate": {$lte: ISODate("2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
                    {"endDate": {$gte: ISODate("2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}

                            ]}}}]},
{$set: { "pointsBalances.$.value": 200 } });
```

Comment: Hi, Priyanka Kariya, Thank you for sugestion but for only startDate condition my solution also works. The problem occurs when we have also condition for the endDate. elementMatch seems to not change anything :(